Remote Desktop app screen flickers/shakes if not full screen
I'm trying to understand if I'm the only one with this problem, but I've seen it on at least a couple of PC so it would be a strange coincidence.
I'm using the new Remote Desktop app, the one you get from the store, on Windows 11 (but it was the same on Windows 10).
When connecting to certain instances, I noticed it especially on WinServer 2012 machines, the screen constantly "flickers"/"shakes", but probably these are not the right words. I mean it keeps briefly resizing by 1 or 2 pixels, making the screen one moment sharp and the next one blurry.
This does not happen if I use full screen mode or if, at least, I maximize the window. It also sometimes stops when I resize the window by 1 pixel or so, probably finding a "balance" situation.

It is likely an issue with one scrollbar changing the dimension of the window just enough to force a redraw, which then suddenly has the other scroll bar not being necessary anymore, and is removed, then that forces the window to resize again and you get in a loop. If this is the case, it will depend on the resolution of your main screen vs the target resolution. It will also matter if you have a resolution set in the RDP itself, and the problem will likely go away if you enable smart sizing, either through the menu from the top-left icon, or by editing it in the RDP file itself.

No, you are talking about the Remote Desktop Connection included in windows. I'm talking about the Remote Desktop app you can download from Microsoft Store which is a completely different software (e.g. it does not work with .rdp files).

But it uses the same protocol, and it can have the same settings, just find it differently.

Protocol is the same but the two apps are radically different. I think it's a bug. Just looking if anyone else suffered from it and maybe found a solution.

EDIT - as I posted this I had an idea. I have changed my "desktop scaling" in desktop>rightclick>display settings from 125% to 150% and it seems to have resolved it!
To add context it's a 4K monitor. I got the flickering at 125%, I don't get it at 150%.
If anyone else comes across this and has any advice, it would be greatly appreciated. I don't want to have to leave my monitor at 150%
I had/have (currently using 150% workaround) this exact same issue described and I haven't been able to solve it. I'm actually semi relieved to see someone else having the exact same issue since during my Googling I struggled to find specifically this issue. I usually got articles about other types of RDP flickering/black screens.

Oh God! I'm semi relieved too! :)
Unfortunately I'm already at 150% scaling (I'm on a 4K monitor too).
